# What is the best practice of groupby in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL that groupbys multiple columns. I was wondering if the order of the columns matter to the query performance.

Does placing the column with more distinct values earlier help? I assume the groupby is based on some hash/shuffle algorithm. If the first groupby can distribute data to small subsets that can be hold in one machine, the later groupbys can be done locally. Is this true?

What is the best practice of groupby?

Answer (score 2):

`group by`, as you assumed, uses hash function on columns to decide which set of group by keys would end up in which partition. 
You can use `distribute by` to tell spark which columns to use - https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/select.html

As for any other manipulation on the data (like placing more distinct values earlier), note that if have 2 `group by` statements in your query, you end up with 2 shuffles. And the result of the first one is obviously quite big (as it's not the final aggregation). So I would try to have as little `group by` statements as possible.

Comment: In all columns C1, C2, .. Cn to groupby, if C1 has more distinct values, we do use 'distribute by C1' to repartition the table first?